# Nonlinear PDE related to zero Hessian

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Consider
$$f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2 =0$$

where $f=f(x,y)$ is a well behaved function. This PDE is the determinant of the Hessian.

Solutions for $f$ are the trivial solution, $f=$constant and $f=ax+by$ for $a,b$ constant.

However, $f=f(x-cy)$ for $c$ a constant also satisfies this equation. This implies there are lines of constant value along $\xi = x-cy$. That is, the curvature alongs these lines is zero which agrees with my intuition as the determinant is proportional to the Gaussian curvature.

Are there more general solutions?

Comment: Just to be a smartass, $f=f(y-cx)$ is also a solution.

Comment: $f=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is also a solution if the origin is excluded.

Comment: I have encountered this PDE before from considering scalar-field theories invariant under Galilean transformation ($\nabla f \to \nabla f + \vec{c}$). In 2D the next to simplest Lagrangian having such a property is $(\nabla f)^2 \nabla^2 f$ whose EL equation is $(\nabla^2 f)^2 - (\nabla_{ij}f)^2 = 2[f_{xx}f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2] = 0$ (only equal to the determinant of the Hessian in 2D though). IIRC there are known soliton solutions for these types of theories, but I suspect they fall under the $f(x-cy)$ type (we also don't have a time-coordinate here so these solitons might not apply in this case).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%E2%80%93Amp%C3%A8re_equation

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the obvious solutions on the form :
$$f(x,y)=F(ax+by+c) \quad\text{ any differentiable function  }F$$
another family of solutions are obtained thanks to the separation of variables method :
$$f(x,y)=C\:(x+x_0)^{1/(1-\lambda)}(y+y_0)^{\lambda/(\lambda-1)}$$
any constants $C$ , $x_0$ , $y_0$ and $\lambda\neq 1$.

[image]